# mmenu change starting positon of slidedown

Tags: javascript, mmenu

perhaps someone can help me.
I'm creating a website and want to use mmenu for my navigation.
What I want is to slide down the menu from the top as seen in https://mmenujs.com/docs/extensions/positioning.html.
I have a navigation bar on top of the page (hamburger button etc.), just like the page mentioned above.
The menu now slides from top OVER this navigation bar. On the page mentioned above you can see exactly the same behavior.
How can I tell the script to start sliding after the navigation bar or just start sliding from a spezial position, e.g. starting 40px from top.
Can somebody please help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change are selectors.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener(
        "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
                new Mmenu( "#my-menu", {
                     "extensions": [
                            "position-back",
                            "position-top"
                     ]
                });
                        
                var header = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
                var navigation = document.getElementsByTagName('nav');
    
                if (header.length && navigation.length) {
                        navigation[0].style.marginTop = header[0].offsetHeight + "px";             
                }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is not working. The slide still starts at the top of the site. But I want to start the slide after the header section. I think it's an Issue with the wrapper classes at the body element, but not sure how to make that work.